# How to detect if a new process is running on timer c#

Tags: c#, winforms, process

How would I find out if a new process is running (not specific, just any new one), and add it to listView with its icon from timer.

Currently I have this, and all it does is reset the listview regardless if a new process is there or not. I want it to not reset the listview, and instead add the new one into the listview. As well, remove processes that are no longer there.

```
public UserControl5()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SHFILEINFO
        {
            public IntPtr hIcon;
            public IntPtr iIcon;
            public uint dwAttributes;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
            public string szDisplayName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
            public string szTypeName;
        };

        class Win32
        {
            public const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x100;
            public const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x0;    // 'Large icon
            public const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x1;    // 'Small icon

            [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath,
                                        uint dwFileAttributes,
                                        ref SHFILEINFO psfi,
                                        uint cbSizeFileInfo,
                                        uint uFlags);
        }

        private int nIndex = 0;
        private void UserControl5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;


        }
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            listView1.Columns.Clear();
            listView1.Columns.Add("Processes");
            listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);

            IntPtr hImgSmall;    //the handle to the system image list
            IntPtr hImgLarge;    //the handle to the system image list
            string fName;        // 'the file name to get icon from
            SHFILEINFO shinfo = new SHFILEINFO();

            listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;
            listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;


            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process process in processlist)
            {
                try
                {
                    String fileName = process.MainModule.FileName;
                    String processName = process.ProcessName;
                    hImgSmall = Win32.SHGetFileInfo(fileName, 0, ref shinfo,
                                                  (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo),
                                                   Win32.SHGFI_ICON |
                                                   Win32.SHGFI_SMALLICON);

                    //Use this to get the large Icon
                    //hImgLarge = SHGetFileInfo(fName, 0,
                    //ref shinfo, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo),
                    //Win32.SHGFI_ICON | Win32.SHGFI_LARGEICON);
                    //The icon is returned in the hIcon member of the shinfo
                    //struct
                    System.Drawing.Icon myIcon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon);

                    imageList1.Images.Add(myIcon);

                    //Add file name and icon to listview



                    listView1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)), nIndex++);
                    //nIndex++


                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
            }

private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            int intselectedindex = listView1.SelectedIndices[0];
            if (intselectedindex >= 0)
            {
                textBox1.Text = listView1.Items[intselectedindex].Text;
            }
        }
```

Comment: And I presume that you want also remove the processes that are no more present.

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry for not including that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1** - As an option you can use a timer and fetch processes information using `Process.GetProcesses()` or using a WMI query on `Win32_Process`. Then compare existing list of processes with new list based on their `ProcessId`. Then you can find processes and removed processes.

**Option 2** - As another option you can use [`ManagementEventWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to monitor [`Win32_ProcessStartTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394374(v=vs.85).aspx) to detect start of new proceses and [`Win32_ProcessStopTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394376(v=vs.85).aspx) to detect stopping processes.

You can subscribe `EventArrived` event of `ManagementEventWatcher` which monitors an object. In this event, you can find informations like `ProcessID` and `ProcessName` about process.

When using the watcher and the event, keep in mind:

- The `EventArrived` will raise in a different thread than UI thread and if you need to manipulate UI, you need to use `Invoke`.
- You should stop the watcher and dispose it in `OnFormClosed`.
- You should add a reference to `System.Management.dll`.
- You should add `using System.Management;`
- You need to run your program as administrator.

**Example**

```
ManagementEventWatcher startWatcher;
ManagementEventWatcher stopWatcher;
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    startWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher("Select * From Win32_ProcessStartTrace");
    startWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(startWatcher_EventArrived);
    stopWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher("Select * From Win32_ProcessStopTrace");
    stopWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(stopWatcher_EventArrived);
    startWatcher.Start();
    stopWatcher.Start();
}
void startWatcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} started", (string)e.NewEvent["ProcessName"]));
}
void stopWatcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} stopped", (string)e.NewEvent["ProcessName"]));
}
protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    startWatcher.Stop();
    stopWatcher.Stop();
    startWatcher.Dispose();
    stopWatcher.Dispose();
    base.OnFormClosed(e);
}
```

Comment: There is no FormClosed in UserControl.

Comment: Test it on a form and then customize it for yourself.

Comment: Well it works. But it requires administrator rights. Is there any fix for that?

Comment: No, there is no fix for that. You can use the first option.